# a type guard function that 1st argument's attribute type is determined by the 2nd string key argument (e.g. key="Dict", then -> TypeGuard["Dict"])?

Tags: python, typeguards

I tried to parse a JSON data into a Python Pydantic class object. The problem is that the data is like

```py
class Data(BaseModel):
    val: Union[Dict, SubData1, SubData2]
    key: str # e.g. "dict_type", "sub_data_type", "sub_data_type2"
```

I'm thinking to make a type guard function (`check_type`) and use it like below:

```py
if check_type(data, "dict_type"):
   value = data.val ## type checker will automatically know it is Dict
elif check_type(data, "sub_data_type"):
   value = data.val ## type checker will automatically know it is SubData1
```

It will allow my IDE to have better maintainability. Is it doable?

Comment: Are you using `3.10+`?

Comment: I'm using 3.9.2 but it is fine to switch to using 3.10+ if it is needed.

Comment: You can define a [type-guard](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0647/) easily, [even before Python 3.10](https://github.com/python/typing/blob/master/typing_extensions/README.rst). Whether it will do what you want it to do is not clear from your limited example.

Answer (score -1):

```py
import typing

@typing.overload
def check_type_1(data: typing.Any, typename: typing.Literal["dict"]) -> typing.TypeGuard[dict]:
    ...

@typing.overload
def check_type_1(data: typing.Any, typename: typing.Literal["list"]) -> typing.TypeGuard[list]:
    ...

def check_type_1(data: typing.Any, typename: str) -> bool:
    if typename == "dict":
        return isinstance(data, dict)
    elif typename == "list":
        return isinstance(data, list)
    else:
        raise NotImplementedError

def test2():
    x: typing.Any = 1
    if check_type_1(x, "dict"):
        print(f"x={x} is dict")
    elif check_type_1(x, "list"):
        print(f"x={x} is list")
    else:
        print(f"x={x} is {type(x)}")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    test2()
```

Try this code in Python 3.10.